# What's the difference between adding a forwardslash and not in bash?

Tags: bash

So I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash

> oldFiles.txt

files=$(grep " jane " ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)

for i in $files ; do
 if test -e ~$i; then echo "$i" >> oldFiles.txt;
 fi
done
```

And when I run those code the oldFiles.txt still empty, but after I added a forwardslash in the if statement like in the codeblock below, the code works.

```
 if test -e ~/$i; then echo "$i" >> oldFiles.txt;
```

So what's the difference between adding a forwardslash and not? Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` is the path delimiter.  Since `~` expands to `/home/user` without a trailing foward slash, `~$i` exapands to `/home/userpath` not `/home/user/path`.